# Since childhood vs. since my childhood

Tags: grammar

is it better to say "since childhood" or "since my childhood" in the following example?

"I have known them since childhood/my childhood"

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Since childhood" is pretty much the standard convention here in the USA. But technically either one would work. Personally, I might also consider saying

> "I have known them since I was little" or "I have known them since I was a child."

Comment: Thank you so very much for your detailed explanations!